# How can I set default sorted direction in lightning datatable?

Tags: lightning, lightning-datatable

I have a datatable which has column of type date. I want to set the default sorting order of the column. That means it should not allow the user to sort but date should be in order of latest date first.
Is that possible ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? please paste some code with your current status so we can know where you are stuck

Answer (score 1):

Set the columns as `sortable: false`, and sort the data after you get it from the server/callout/whatever. You have full control over the data returned, so there's nothing to prevent you from sorting the data:

```
if(state === 'SUCCESS') {
  let sortedData = 
    result.getReturnValue()
    .sort((a,b)=>a.someField-b.someField);
```

Comment: var result = response.getReturnValue();
var sortedData = result.sort((a,b)=>a.Name-b.Name);
 cmp.set('v.data', sortedData);    I tried like this..but it doesn't give me sorted names in ascending order . Also how can I use this for Date.

Comment: Basically I need latest date first.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sortDirection atrribute you can use this atrribute to specify sorting direction
Here is the sample code

```
  updateColumnSorting(event) {
        var fieldName = event.detail.fieldName;
        var sortDirection = event.detail.sortDirection;
        // assign the latest attribute with the sorted column fieldName and sorted direction
        this.sortedBy = fieldName;
        this.sortedDirection = sortDirection;
        this.data = this.sortData(fieldName, sortDirection);
   }
```

Comment: Actually what I want is I should not allow the user to sort. Data table should have default sorted direction. Nothing should happen from the user end. I should be sorted in asc direction.

Answer (score 0):

Use  ORDER BY clause in the apex controller from which you are receiving data and populating the data-table -->
a) to sort by one column : ORDER BY YOURFIELD1
b) to sort by two/multiple columns :  ORDER BY YOURFIELD1, YOURFIELD2

also to restrict user from manually sorting : remove  'sortable: true' from column def .

Answer (score 0):

For LWC I did something similar to what sfdcfox mentioned, with an adjustment from another answer specific to javascript (https://stackoverflow.com/a/69754377).

```
finalData.sort((a,b) => Date.parse(b.CreatedDate) - Date.parse(a.CreatedDate));
```